# JQuery On() not working for div

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an asp.net page with UpdatePanel and like to make a scroll event hander persist through Ajax calls. I got it working for input element change event (see last example), but I am struggle with the sroll event for the div element.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

/* working event fires but not after ajax call */
$("#ctl00_cirsContent_divReportLeft").on("scroll", function() {
    alert("test scroll left");
});

/* this one does not work at all */
$(document).on("scroll", "#ctl00_cirsContent_divReportRight", function () {
    alert("Test scroll");

});

/* this one works both before and after ajax call */
$(document).on("change", "#ctl00_cirsContent_CtlCalendar1_txtDate", function () {
    alert("Test type");

});

});
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Please note: *mere idea* -> if you are using C# user control and this input `id` => `ctl00_cirsContent_divReportLeft` is dynamically generated I would recommend you to use `class` attribute. This should work. Good detail here: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$(window)` instead of `$(document)`:

```
$(window).on("scroll", "#ctl00_cirsContent_divReportRight", function () {
    alert("Test scroll");
});
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't make any difference, does not work either.

Comment: You can try to use class instead of `id` like Tats_innit suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this solution using the pageLoad event rather than $(document).ready:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
   if (args.get_isPartialLoad())
   {
    registerScrollEvent();
   }
}
```

and this in registerScrollEvent

```
$("div[id$='divReportLeft']").scroll(function () { 
.... some code
   });
```